Dependency conflict due to multiple versions of questionary package
requirement.txt
commitizen==3.27.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of questionary to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting questionary<3.0,>=2.0 (from commitizen==3.27.0->-r .\requirements.txt (line 34))
  Downloading questionary-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install -r .\requirements.txt (line 75), commitizen and prompt_toolkit==3.0.45 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested prompt_toolkit==3.0.45
    ipython 8.25.0 depends on prompt-toolkit<3.1.0 and >=3.0.41
    questionary 2.0.1 depends on prompt_toolkit<=3.0.36 and >=2.0
    The user requested prompt_toolkit==3.0.45
    ipython 8.25.0 depends on prompt-toolkit<3.1.0 and >=3.0.41
    questionary 2.0.0 depends on prompt_toolkit<=3.0.36 and >=2.0

I have tried recreating virtual environments, clearing pip cache directory, uninstalling packages and reinstall. Nothing worked
